# usage of the operator >>> (Zero-fill right shift) in Array.prototype.find (polyfill)

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I was looking at this function `Array.prototype.find` from ([mdn polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)):

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

i don't understand the goal of this code:

```
var length = list.length >>> 0;
```

Comment: @RGraham -- not a dupe (at least not of that question).  The other question is asking what the op is.  This one is asking "why the hell would you use it here?"  :)

Comment: @zyklus The answer in the duplicate answers that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x >>> 0` forces `x` to become an integer. Thus, if `list` is an array, `length` shall be its length; but if `.length` doesn't exist, or is something silly like `{a: 17, length: "Unicorns"}`, `length` will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit "cast to int" inherent in any javascript binary ops.  So `3.14159 >>> 0 === 3`, and any invalid values, like `'foo'` get cast to `0`

Why `>>>` instead of `>>` or `|`?  Apparently they're expecting *huge* arrays (but not too huge):

```
Math.pow(2,31)>>0
-2147483648

Math.pow(2,31)>>>0
2147483648
```

Comment: @Amadan -- You're right, I'm tired :P